# How many classes of dangerous beast are there in Akame ga Kill?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

There are many dangerous beasts in Akame ga Kill, and the strongest class is Ultra class dangerous beast, this is one of them:

> [image: Kurome's Desta Ghoul]

Is there any other class beside Ultra and Normal class?

Comment: I think we can say no. See here but there are SPOILER --> http://akamegakill.wikia.com/wiki/Danger_Beasts

Comment: at a guess, it's probably a completely arbitrary rating, much like power levels in japanese. It has no concrete meaning. It's just there to build hype for a big fight.

Answer (score 1):

The less dangerous to the more dangerous

- Level 4
- Level 3
- Level 2
- Level 1
- Supreme level
- Ultra level

I put here an image from the french manga :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time, there is no known ranking system for the *Danger Beast*. Nor is there any other known rank besides the regular *Danger Beast* and the *Ultra Class Danger Beast*. And even for this rank we do not know what the requirements are.

All that we can assume is that the *Ultra Class* is a rare occurrence, of whom the most already have been eradicated and turned into Teigu.

Long story short:
 **No, there are no other danger beast classes besides regular and ultra at this point in time**